# ggplot2 x label does not start from the first month

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set (in xts format) which I wanted to plot using ggplot2 package. Everything works pertty much fine except that labels in x-axis start from Feb instead of Jan.

Details of my data:

```
USCPI_YEARLY = as.xts(c(1.399770, 1.676215, 2.619763, 4.159695, 4.992707, 5.391451, 5.365475, 5.251272, 5.390349, 6.221869, 6.809003, 7.036403, 7.479872, 7.871064, 8.542456, 8.258629, 8.581512, 9.059758, 8.524815, 8.262693, 8.201670, 7.745427, 7.110323, 6.454401, 6.410147, 6.035613, 4.984974, 4.930320, 4.047609, 2.969178, 3.177780, 3.665112, 3.699698, 3.241145, 3.137271, 3.352123), as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", "2021-05-01","2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", "2021-10-01","2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", "2022-03-01","2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", "2022-08-01","2022-09-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-11-01", "2022-12-01", "2023-01-01","2023-02-01", "2023-03-01", "2023-04-01", "2023-05-01", "2023-06-01","2023-07-01", "2023-08-01", "2023-09-01", "2023-10-01", "2023-11-01", "2023-12-01")))
names(USCPI_YEARLY) = "USCPI"
```

Below works correctly, but x-axis label starts from Feb. I want it to start from Jan.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(data = window(USCPI_YEARLY, start = "2021-01-01"), aes(x = Index, y = USCPI)) + geom_point() + geom_line() +
  ggtitle("US CPI", subtitle = "US Inflation peaked in Jun'22 and continues to decline") + ylab("CPI (in %)") + xlab("") +
  scale_x_date(
    breaks = date_breaks("3 months"),
    labels = scales::label_date_short()
    )
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsJSK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(data = USCPI_YEARLY, aes(x = Index, y = USCPI)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("US CPI", subtitle = "US Inflation peaked in Jun'22 and continues to decline") +
  ylab("CPI (in %)") +
  xlab("") +
  scale_x_date(
    breaks = seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), max(index(USCPI_YEARLY)), by = "3 month"),
    labels = scales::label_date_short()
    )
```

[correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms2i9.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not work. The output is the same.

Comment: I edited it, I can't run the code right now so I can't check if it's working properly. I'm blindly trying.

Comment: I've just placed reproducible code, hopefully, it will help you.

Comment: Your code actually worked with a small adjustment.                                 
ggplot(data = USCPI_YEARLY, aes(x = Index, y = USCPI)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("US CPI", subtitle = "US Inflation peaked in Jun'22 and continues to decline") +
  ylab("CPI (in %)") +
  xlab("") +
  scale_x_date(
    breaks = seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), max(index(USCPI_YEARLY)), by = "3 month"),
    labels = scales::label_date_short()
    )

Comment: Glad if I could help.